# Remove all rows (tr) from an HTML table with a specific substring in the id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want to delete all rows from a specific html table, where the id of the row (tr) contains a specific substring.

Do I have to `foreach` over all the rows or is there a quicker way?

I'm thinking of something like this, but I think I'm on the wrong path:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.find("tr").id.contains("somesubstring").remove();
```

Comment: The suggested duplicate post does not address the substrings of the id's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, then the following is one way to do this, by using [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('#myTable tr[id*=somesubstring]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all the `tr` and then use `includes` to check if the id `contains` a specific string. In this example it is checking if `id` contains 'test'

```js
function removeRow() {
  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.id.includes('test')) {
      item.remove();
      }
    })
   }
```

```html
<table border='1px solid black'>
  <tr id='test'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='rtt'>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='weftest'>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='vsfvsfv'>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='yukyktest'>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='sfsvfsfv'>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type='button' onclick='removeRow()'>Remove</button>
```